# Why does “=“ work but “+” gives a warning (Swift)

Tags: swift

I am confused as to why “=“ successfully changes the variable but “+” does not and brings back a warning. I would also like to know how to make “+” work.
[What I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRRVt.jpg)

Comment: because = is an assignment operator, in the + is arithmetic operator, you may use score += 10 instead or score = score + 10 to achieve what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be looking for a compound assignment operator like `+=`.

- `score = 10` makes sense: it’s a statement which sets the score to 10
- `score += 10` also makes sense: it’s a statement which increases score by 10
- but `score + 10` does not: it’s an expression which just evaluates to an unused result.